# When I try to open a project, Quartus opens and then closes itself

Tags: quartus

I'm not fully sure why this is happening.
I also think it's important to say that this is only happening for one of my specific projects. I am still able to open other perfectly.

Comment: Is it any project or a specific one? If latter, it could be just corrupt. In this case you should create a new one and import the sources from the original.

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's a specific one, is there anything I can do to fix this without trying to create a new project?

Comment: I doubt it. Try another quartus version.

Answer (score 4):

It's possible that your project database is corrupt. Try deleting the following directories in your quartus project directory:

```
\db
\incremental_db
```

**NOTE: deleting these directoires will force you to do a full project recompile.** 
These directories are generated by Quartus at compile time, so you won't lose any of your project settings by deleting them. Project settings are stored in your `<project>.qsf`file.

Opening the project with a different version of Quartus will achieve the same effect as Quartus will not open a project built using a different version without deleting these directories first.

If that doesn't work, there may be a bad setting in your `<project>.qsf` file. This will be trickier to fix. You could make a fresh blank copy of the `<project>.qsf` and incrementally import settings (global assignments, source assignments, pin assignments, etc> and open your project until quartus fails, or just start over and redo all of your project settings if it's not a big project and the .qsf file is fairly simple.